# Quality Control Tests for hardware

Tags: testing, test

We are in the process of creating a quality assurance & control department at work.
I need to define different tests for the hardware that we make.
The devices are composed of multiple pcbs, with ICs and a micro-controller, using voltage <= 48 DC.

I already have in mind tests such as:

- Functional tests
- Noise tests (on communication cables)
- Temperature test
- Surge immunity test

I would like to make the list as exhaustive as possible.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you measure **quality** of a manufacturing process? Not with functional tests. This is a very broad topic that is difficult to answer definitively, so not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Physical drop/shake tests, EMC tests, max current/voltage limit tests, voltage spike tests, ground/safety tests, ...

Comment: Questions that seek a list are too broad for stack exchange sites - they are reserved for specific questions that can have specific answers.

Comment: start with the tests that are required for legal compliance with all the territories you supply to, then the functional tests that tell you whether it works, then the environmental tests that tell you whether it will shake apart and melt in transit, then the manufacturing quality tests that tell you whether your manufacturing process is doing what you think it's doing. I've probably forgotten some vital other tests.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do realize and agree this is a broad question. However, I posted it because I believe it can provide help to others.

Comment: We call this DVT which ought to include margin tests from stresses defined from voltage interfaces error rate with SNR reduced injected  from EMI  suite of tests, climatic, mechanical and sometime altitude tests.,Sometimes HALT tests are done to assess MTBF margins. I spent a few years in my career becoming an expert in this then managed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests fall into two broad categories:

**Design Verification** - does the design do what it is supposed to do under a wide enough range of external conditions? This includes:

- Functional testing
- Margin testing - e.g., over temperature, supply voltage, clock speed, etc.
- Compliance testing - relative to regulatory standards
- Mechanical testing (shake, drop tests)
- Thermal analysis

**Manufacturing** - can you repeatedly build reliable units? This includes:

- Parts inpsection
- Assembly inspection - missing parts, orientation, soldering, etc.
- Functional testing

The latter category — quality management — is what is covered by the [ISO900x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9000) series of standards.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider reading the ETSI EN 300 019 series of test specs.  While these tests specs were made for telecom, they provide a good list of the kinds of tests you may want to use to ensure the quality and reliability of electronics assemblies: 
• temperature
• humidity, 
• air pressure and speed
• insolation
• water ingress
• chemically active substances
• mechanically active substances
• mechanical vibration and shock
• flora and fauna
• etc.  
All defined in the specs.  Best of all the specs can be downloaded for free.

You can google "ETSI EN 300 019".  You can go to their website, https://www.etsi.org/.  But probably you want to start with a couple of specs to get you going.

Example test spec:
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_i_ets/300001_300099/3000190103/01_60/ets_3000190103e01p.pdf

Overview:
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_i_ets/300001_300099/3000190100/01_60/ets_3000190100e01p.pdf

In terms of EMI/EMC testing, there is a good list at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_EMC_test_standards

such as:

• IEC EN 61000-4-2, Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC)- Part 4-2: Testing and measurement techniques - Electrostatic discharge immunity test

• IEC EN 61000-4-3, Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC)- Part 4-3: Testing and measurement techniques - Radiated, radio-frequency, electromagnetic field immunity test

• IEC EN 61000-4-4, Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) - Part 4-4: Testing and measurement techniques - Electrical fast transient/burst immunity test

• IEC EN 61000-4-5, Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) - Part 4-5: Testing and measurement techniques - Surge immunity test

• IEC EN 61000-4-6, Electromagnetic compatibility (EMC) - Part 4-6: Testing and measurement techniques - Immunity to conducted disturbances, induced by radio-frequency fields

You can also perform reliability tests such as Accelerated Life Testing, Stress Testing.